# Obtaining overlapping matches using a regex

Tags: perl

See code first plz~

This is perl code.

```
my $st = 'aaaa';

while ( $st =~ /aa/g ) {
    print $&, "\n";
}
```

I want to move one point of the string.

So I want the results of the three `aa`.

However, only two results are obtained.

I can derive three results do?

Answer (score 2):

```
my $st = 'aaaa';
my $find = 'aa';

while($st =~ /$find/g){
    print $&,"\n";
    pos($st) -= (length($find)-1);
}
```

From [`perldoc pos`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pos.html)

> Returns the offset of where the last m//g search left off for the variable in question ($_ is used when the variable is not specified)

Also `pos()` is [lvalue subroutine](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html#Lvalue-subroutines) and result from it can be changed like for variable.

Answer (score 1):

Use a look ahead. It doesn't advance the position:

```
my $st = 'abcd';

while ($st =~ /(?=(..))/g) {
    print "$1\n";
}
```

I used a different string to make the matching positions visible.

Answer (score 1):

The following will do the trick:

```
while ($st =~ /(?=(aa))/g) {
   print "$1\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that regular expressions do not normally allow overlapping matches.

You can explore this fact by outputting the [Positional Information](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Position-information) for your two current matches:

```
my $st = 'aaaa';

while ( $st =~ /aa/g ) {
    print "pos $-[0] - $&\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
pos 0 - aa
pos 2 - aa
```

To fix this, you simply need to use a [Positive Lookahead Assertion](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Looking-ahead-and-looking-behind) and an explicit [capture group](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Extracting-matches):

```
while ( $st =~ /(?=(aa))/g ) {
    print "pos $-[0] - $1\n";
}
```

Outputs:

```
pos 0 - aa
pos 1 - aa
pos 2 - aa
```